# Deriving Duhamel's Principle

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to understand Duhamel's principle by going through its derivation. This is what I have found so far (from a few texts such as Logan's Applied Partial Differential Equations).

Suppose we have the ODE
$$\begin{cases} y'(t) + ay = F(t) \quad t> 0\\~y(0) = \phi\end{cases}$$
Multiplying both sides of the ODE by an integrating factor $e^{\int a dt}$ give us
$$\frac{d}{dt}(e^{at}y)  = e^{at}F(t)$$
We then integrate both sides
$$\int_0^t \frac{d}{d\tau}\bigl(e^{a\tau}y(\tau)\bigr)d\tau = \int_0^te^{a\tau}F(\tau)d\tau\\
\implies e^{at}y(t) - y(0) = \int_0^te^{a\tau}F(\tau)d\tau\\
\implies y(t) = y(0) + \int_0^te^{-a(t-\tau)}F(\tau)d\tau = \phi + \int_0^te^{-a(t-\tau)}F(\tau)d\tau$$
Next, we consider the homogenous version of the ODE above, but move the source term to the initial condition. That is,
$$\begin{cases}w'(t;\tau) +aw(t;\tau) = 0, \quad t>0\\w(0;\tau) = F(\tau)\end{cases}$$
In his text, Logan claims it is straightforward to see that the solution to this homogenous ODE is $$w(t;\tau) = F(\tau)e^{-at}$$
From this he concludes that the solution of our original ODE is simply the integral of $w$, but with $t$ replaced by $t-\tau$. Hence,
$$y(t) = \int_0^t w(t-\tau;\tau)F(\tau)d\tau = \int_0^t F(\tau)e^{-a(t-\tau)}d\tau$$

I have a few questions about this all. I understand how to solve the original ODE using an integrating factor, that is trivial. However I am unclear on a few things that following this. For example,

1. What is the motivation behind moving the source term to the initial condition?
2. How does it follow that the solution of our original ODE is the integral of $w$, but with $t$ replaced by $t-\tau$? Is this just done by inspection or is there some deeper implication with this change of variables?
3. I do not fully understand the semicolon notation inside the function, does $w(t;\tau)$ represent two separate variables, or is $\tau$ a parametrization of $t$?